# CSS / Overlap issues

Tags: css

I am not very good at this I know some but I am having some issues with my CSS I can not figure out.

My mainContent ID overlaps with under my Sidebar ID. I am sure I messed up my css trying to fix this but I have no idea how to fix t his.  I have changed things so many times I have become lost.

Any help would be nice.

```
@charset "utf-8";
body  {

    background:  #A00;
    margin: 0; 
    text-align: center; 
    color: #A00;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.twoColHybLtHdr #container {
    width: 80%;
    background: #CFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid #A00;
    text-align: left;
    border-color: #A00;
    float: right;
} 
.twoColHybLtHdr #header {
    background-image:url(img/background3.png);
    padding: 12px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left;
} 


.twoColHybLtHdr #sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 14em;
    background: #006633;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: #D4DFAA;
    border: #A00;
}
.twoColHybLtHdr #sidebar1 h3, {
    margin-left: 10px; 
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px;

}

.twoColHybLtHdr #sidebar1 p {
    margin-left: 10px; 
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px;
}


.twoColHybLtHdr #mainContent {
    margin: 5px 20px ;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #000;
} 
.twoColHybLtHdr #footer {
    padding: 50px 8px; 
    background:#FFFF99;
    background-color: #FF9;
} 
.twoColHybLtHdr #footer p {
    font:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif, 10px;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 10px 0; 
    border-color: #666666;

}

.fltrt { 
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.fltlft { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.clearfloat { 
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}

.twoColHybLtHdr #table {
    font:
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;

y background-color: #8B0000;
; background-color: #A00;
border: #A00;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what's going on at the bottom with `y background-color: #8B0000;`. Can you add your HTML? Can you make a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: could we see a demo site or a http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's happening as there isn't a visual on whats actually happening.

```
.twoColHybLtHdr #sidebar1 h3, {
```

Just remove the **,** and all should be good

The bottom there is a few errors.

```
.twoColHybLtHdr #table {
**font:**
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
color: #FFF;

**y** background-color: #8B0000;
; background-color: #A00;
border: #A00;
}
```

I'm guessing it should be more like

```
.twoColHybLtHdr #table {
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;

.y{
    background-color: #8B0000;
    background-color: #A00;
    border: #A00;
}
```

Comment: Protip: You could actually just use `font-family: sans-serif;` and the system will generally use Helvetica for OSX and Arial for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify a width on BOTH the `.fltrt` and `.fltlft` columns

Your css should look like this:

```
/** Assuming the parent element (container) is 940px wide **/

.fltlft {
    float: left;
    width: 540px;
}

.fltrt {
    float: right;
    width: 380px;
}
```

Also, make sure you replace/remove `**y**` with `.y` and remove that unused `**font**` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Take the float right off of the container
put a float left on the main content
add a div after the main content that clears both.

```
.twoColHybLtHdr #container {
width: 80%;
background: #CFF;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 2px solid #A00;
text-align: left;
border-color: #A00;
******** removed Float:right;
} 

.twoColHybLtHdr #sidebar1 {
float: left;
width: 210px;  ****** Change this to pixels unless you are specifying the font-size as !important otherwise you could have problems with this width scaling unintentionally.
background: #006633;
padding: 5px 0;
background-color: #D4DFAA;
border: #A00;
}

.twoColHybLtHdr #mainContent {
margin: 5px 20px ;
padding-left: 15px;
color: #000;
float: left; ****** Added float left to mesh it with your sidebar float right would work as well but wouldn't mesh it with your floated sidebar.
} 

*********** add another div after your mainContent and assign it the ID="clear" 
.twoColHybLtHdr #clear {
clear: left; 
}
```

There are some other errors in your css but I think these are the ones where you are having your problems.

Comment: without seeing the HTML I am guessing a little but based on the css this appears to make the most sense.